# Rails setting a maximum length on a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The is the first time I've set a string length maximum in Rails.

It looks like I can add this to the workorder model:

```
validates_length_of :description, :maximum => 100
```

And I can create a migration with this:

```
change_column :workorders, :description, :string,  :limit => 100
```

Do I need both?

Comment: You only need the first one, see Mori's answer to know why the second one is "just" an additional security. The first one is Rails verifying stuff before writing in database. The second one is enforced directly at db level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should definitely include it in the migration, because this defines the actual structure of your database. This will also constrain the maximum storage size limit of the column (past a certain point, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html for more details). Additionally, it's possible for more than just your Rails App to touch the database.

Including it in the validation is just good practice for robustness, though not strictly required.